# Laravel 9 send Vonage sms to user with multiple phone numbers

Tags: php, laravel, sms, laravel-9, vonage

I am working on a `Laravel 9` project and I've been following the documentation from the `Laravel` website. I managed to get the sms to work for a single phone number but the user has multiple phone numbers and I can't figure out how to send sms to all of them. There is no documentation for that on the `Laravel` website and can't find information on google.

Here is my notification class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\VonageMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;

class SmsNotification extends Notification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(public string $message)
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['vonage'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the mail representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return \Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage
     */
    public function toVonage($notifiable)
    {
        return (new VonageMessage())
                    ->content($this->message);
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

Here is how I call it:

```
$user = User::with(['phones', 'alarmEmails'])->findOrFail($userId);

// phone sms notifications
$message = "{$device->name},\n{$device->location},\n{$text}";
$user->notify(new SmsNotification($message));
```

Here is the method on my `User` class:

```
/**
 * Route notifications for the Vonage channel.
 */
public function routeNotificationForVonage(Notification $notification): array
{
    //return $this->phones->toArray()[0]['number']; // this works
    return array_map(fn($phone) => $phone['number'], $this->phones->toArray()); // this does not work
}
```

Here is the stacktrace when I try to return array of phone numbers from the `routeNotificationForVonage` method on my `User` class:

```
TypeError: Vonage\Message\Message::__construct(): Argument #1 ($idOrTo) must be of type string, array given, called in /var/www/iot-center/vendor/vonage/client-core/src/Message/Client.php on line 515 in file /var/www/iot-center/vendor/vonage/client-core/src/Message/Message.php on line 71

#0 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/vonage/client-core/src/Message/Client.php(515): Vonage\Message\Message-&gt;__construct()
#1 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/vonage/client-core/src/Message/Client.php(153): Vonage\Message\Client-&gt;createMessageFromArray()
#2 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/vonage-notification-channel/src/Channels/VonageSmsChannel.php(69): Vonage\Message\Client-&gt;send()
#3 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(148): Illuminate\Notifications\Channels\VonageSmsChannel-&gt;send()
#4 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(106): Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender-&gt;sendToNotifiable()
#5 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/Localizable.php(19): Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender-&gt;Illuminate\Notifications\{closure}()
#6 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(109): Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender-&gt;withLocale()
#7 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/NotificationSender.php(79): Illuminate\Notifications\NotificationSender-&gt;sendNow()
#8 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/ChannelManager.php(39): Illuminate\Noti
BODY: fications\NotificationSender-&gt;send()
#9 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Notifications/RoutesNotifications.php(18): Illuminate\Notifications\ChannelManager-&gt;send()
#10 /var/www/iot-center/app/Helpers/Notification.php(67): App\User-&gt;notify()
#11 /var/www/iot-center/app/Actions/DeviceMessageProcessor.php(330): App\Helpers\Notification::send_notification()
#12 /var/www/iot-center/app/Actions/DeviceMessageProcessor.php(139): App\Actions\DeviceMessageProcessor-&gt;saveSensorDataPlusNotification()
#13 /var/www/iot-center/app/Actions/DeviceMessageProcessor.php(86): App\Actions\DeviceMessageProcessor-&gt;processPayload()
#14 /var/www/iot-center/app/Http/Controllers/Receive/MessageController.php(81): App\Actions\DeviceMessageProcessor-&gt;process()
#15 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php(54): App\Http\Controllers\Receive\MessageController-&gt;index()
#16 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php(43): Illuminate\Routing\Controller-&gt;callAction()
#17 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(260): Illuminate\Routing\ControllerDispatcher-&gt;dispatch()
#18 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php(205): Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;runController()
#19 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(727): Illuminate\Routing\Route-&gt;run()
#20 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;Illuminate\Routing\{closure}()
#21 /var/www/iot-center/app/Http/Middleware/SetLocale.php(28): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#22 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): App\Http\Middleware\SetLocale-&gt;handle()
#23 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php(50): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#24 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings-&gt;handle()
#25 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(126): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#26 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(102): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handleRequest()
#27 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/ThrottleRequests.php(54): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handleRequestUsingNamedLimiter()
#28 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\ThrottleRequests-&gt;handle()
#29 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#30 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(728): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#31 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(705): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRouteWithinStack()
#32 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(669): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;runRoute()
#33 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php(658): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatchToRoute()
#34 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(190): Illuminate\Routing\Router-&gt;dispatch()
#35 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(141): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;Illuminate\Foundation\Http\{closure}()
#36 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#37 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ConvertEmptyStringsToNull.php(31): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle()
#38 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ConvertEmptyStringsToNull-&gt;handle()
#39 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php(21): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#40 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TrimStrings.php(40): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TransformsRequest-&gt;handle()
#41 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\TrimStrings-&gt;handle()
#42 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php(27): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#43 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\ValidatePostSize-&gt;handle()
#44 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance.php(86): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#45 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\PreventRequestsDuringMaintenance-&gt;handle()
#46 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http/Middleware/TrustProxies.php(39): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#47 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(180): Illuminate\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies-&gt;handle()
#48 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php(116): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}()
#49 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(165): Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline-&gt;then()
#50 /var/www/iot-center/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php(134): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;sendRequestThroughRouter()
#51 /var/www/iot-center/public/index.php(52): Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Kernel-&gt;handle()
#52 {main}
```

Comment: I think you'll want to loop over all the users numbers and send the SMS individually. Also, please link the documentation you are following.